# BeautifulSoup / Python - Convert HTML table to CSV and get href for one column

Tags: python, html, csv, beautifulsoup

I am grabbing an HTML table with this code :

```
import csv
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('listing.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for i in range(39):
        url = "file:///C:/projects/HTML/Export.htm".format(i)
        u = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        try:
            html = u.read()
        finally:
            u.close()
        soup=BeautifulSoup(html)
        for tr in soup.find_all('tr')[2:]:
            tds = tr.find_all('td')
            row = [elem.text.encode('utf-8') for elem in tds]
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Everything works perfectly, but I am trying to grab column 9 Href URL. It is currently giving me the txt value but not the URL.

Also, I have two tables in my HTML, anyway to skip the first table and just build the csv file using the second table?

Any help is very welcomed as I am new to Python and need this for a project I am automating a daily conversion.

Many thanks!

Comment: Hi RobertB, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please leave your question in its original form, except for adding *clarifying* details, so that the answers will still be relevant and useful. If you have unresolved issues, you can *clarify* with further edits, *comment* on one of the answers below, or *ask another question* if it is truly a separate issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should access the `href` attribute of the `a` tag within the 8th `td` tag:

```
import csv
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

records = []
for index in range(39):
    url = get_url(index)  # where is the formatting in your example happening?
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    try:
        html = response.read()
    except Exception:
        raise
    else:
        my_parse(html)
    finally:
        try:
            response.close()
        except (UnboundLocalError, NameError):
            raise UnboundLocalError

def my_parse(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    table2 = soup.find_all('table')[1]
    for tr in table2.find_all('tr')[2:]:
        tds = tr.find_all('td')
        url = tds[8].a.get('href')
        records.append([elem.text.encode('utf-8') for elem in tds])
        # perhaps you want to update one of the elements of this last
        # record with the found url now?

# It's more efficient to write only once
with open('listing.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(records)
```

I have taken the liberty to define a function `get_url` based on the index because your example rereads the same file every time, which is something I guess you don't actually want. I'll leave the implementation to you. Also, I've added some better exception handling.

At the same time, I've shown how you can access the 2nd table from that webpage's tables.

Comment: Looks great thanks for the help!!!I made a few modifications liemputting the my_parse definite before the function is called and inserting the local file url.

Just trying to figure out how to do the update to the last row so the url is pulled to the table.

Comment: At the place where my comment suggests it, you could write: `records[-1][6] = url`. That will overwrite the `text` value of that record by the `href` attribute found earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Was fully able to get it working with the following code:

```
import csv
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Grab second table from HTML
def my_parse(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    table2 = soup.find_all('table')[1]
    for tr in table2.find_all('tr')[2:]:
        tds = tr.find_all('td')
        url = tds[8].a.get('href')
    tds[8].a.replaceWith(url)
        records.append([elem.text.encode('utf-8') for elem in tds])

records = []
#Read HTML file into memory
for index in range(39):
    url = "file:///C:/projects/HTML/Export.htm".format(index)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    try:
        html = response.read()
    except Exception:
        raise
    else:
        my_parse(html)
    finally:
        try:
            response.close()
        except (UnboundLocalError, NameError):
            raise UnboundLocalError

#Writing CSV file
with open('listing.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(records)
```

Many thanks for all the help!!!!!

Comment: Consider accepting your own answer then (and upvoting those that were useful). That's the way Stackoverflow works. ;-)